# React Testing Library Accessible Name

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am confused, isn't the content of the element considered as part of it's accessible name, why does the below test fail to find the alert with the text?

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <div role="alert">Please wait</div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

test("renders alert", async () => {
  render(<Counter />);
  const loadingScreen = await screen.findByRole("alert", {
    name: /Please wait/i
  });
  expect(loadingScreen).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/#accessiblenamecalculation) documentation, the `div` element in your case matches the last rule.

> Other elements The `title` attribute.

Why? Because the `div` element with the `alert` role does not support getting their name from the content they contain. For example, the following link is named "Home".

```html
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

> When assistive technologies render an element that gets its accessible name from its content, such as a link or button, the accessible name is the only content the user can perceive for that element.

**Note: Not all accessible names of element and role are the text content of the element!**

Elements having one of the following roles are, by default, named by a string calculated from their descendant content. See the full list [Roles Supporting Name from Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#namefromcontent)

Two choices:

1. Use the `title` attribute

```html
<div role='alert' title='Please wait'>
    Please wait...
</div>
```

2. Use the `aria-label` attribute

```html
<div role='alert' aria-label='Please wait'>
    Please wait...
</div>
```

Below is a test example, we can create a `div` element with a `'heading'` role, and find it by role and its accessible name(the text content of it).

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';

function Counter() {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{count}</div>
            <div role='alert' aria-label='Please wait'>
                Please wait...
            </div>
            <div role='heading'>An example heading</div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click me</button>
        </div>
    );
}

test('renders alert', async () => {
    render(<Counter />);
    const loadingScreen = await screen.findByRole('alert', {
        name: /Please wait/i,
    });
    expect(loadingScreen).toBeInTheDocument();

    const heading = await screen.findByRole('heading', { name: /An example heading/i });
    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS  stackoverflow/76800902/index.test.tsx
  ✓ renders alert (54 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.289 s, estimated 2 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: Thank you, I was very confused. This makes sense.

Comment: @Jeffery Updated answer, add a `div` element with `role='heading'`. We can find it by its role and its accessible name(the text content of it).